# Correct way to store and retrieve SHA-256 hashed and salted passwords

Tags: php, security, hash, passwords, salt

This is my first attempt in securely storing passwords and I would like to make sure that everything is done correctly. I was advised to use SHA-256 hashing alongside salt.

Assuming user submitted their password thorough form, we get the password via

```
$password = $_POST["password"];
```

What is correct way to salt $password and use SHA-256 hashing on it, so it can than be stored in a password field "password CHAR(64)" in a database?

Once done and stored how would I than compare value stored in a database to one user entered in a login form? Lets assume `$loginPassword = $_POST["loginPassword"];` is what user entered.

Comment: Advice to use SHA-256? That's not [what I've heard](http://es1.php.net/manual/en/faq.passwords.php#faq.passwords.fasthash).

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario Interesting, what would you suggest as an alternative hashing method used today? Preferably secure and fast? I assume it can be applied via same logic as SHA ?

Comment: It cannot be secure *and* fast. The tip to use Blowfish in the linked manual page is fine IMHO. (There're some other similar algorithms but they're specifically designed to be slow, just like Blowflish.)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Secure hash and salt for PHP passwords](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/401656/secure-hash-and-salt-for-php-passwords)

Comment: Use the [`crypt()`](http://php.net/crypt) function; it takes care of the salt for you, if you're interested.

Comment: Also see Openwall's [PHP password hashing framework](http://www.openwall.com/phpass/) (PHPass). Its portable and hardened against a number of common attacks on user passwords. The guy who wrote the framework (SolarDesigner) is the same guy who wrote [John The Ripper](http://www.openwall.com/john/) and sits as a judge in the [Password Hashing Competition](http://password-hashing.net/). So he knows a thing or two about attacks on passwords.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using SHA family methods, you can use the [`crypt()`](http://php.net/crypt) function to salt it for you.

Here is an example script (save and login) using PDO.

**Save password in DB**

```
<?php
// Set the password
$password = 'mypassword';

// Get the hash, letting the salt be automatically generated
$hash = crypt($password);

echo $hash; // for testing purposes only

$mysql_username = 'username'; // for DB
$mysql_password = 'password'; // for DB

$dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=database_name', $mysql_username, $mysql_password);

$stmt = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO table_name (name,pass) VALUES (:name,:pass)");
$stmt->bindParam(':name', $name);
$stmt->bindParam(':pass', $pass);

// insert rows
// $name = $_POST['name'];
// $name = $_POST['pass'];

$name = "username";
$pass = $hash;
$stmt->execute();
```

**Login script**

```
<?php
$mysql_username = 'username'; // for DB
$mysql_password = 'password'; // for DB

$dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=database_name', $mysql_username, $mysql_password);

/*
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
*/

$username = "username";
$password = "mypassword";

$sql = "SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE name=:username";
$statement = $dbh->prepare($sql);
$statement->bindValue(':username',$username,PDO::PARAM_STR);

if($statement->execute())
{
    if($statement->rowCount() == 1)
    {
        $row = $statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

 if (crypt($password, $row['pass']) === $row['pass'])

        {
            $username = $row['name'];
            $email = $row['email'];

echo "Stage 1";

echo "<hr noshade size=\"1\">";

echo "Hello " .$username;

            exit;
        }
        else
        {
            // include "error_login.php";

echo "Stage 2 - ERROR";

        }
    }
    else
    {
       // include "error_login.php";

echo "Stage 3 error";
    }
}
```

Comment: Just few questions, in Login script when you bindBalue :username what is PDO::PARAM_STR used for? similarly PDO::FETCH_ASSOC ? This is first time I see those.

Comment: [`This page`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.constants.php) will explain it in better detail. @Ilja and the [`PDO manual`](http://www.php.net/PDO)

Comment: Crypt used in this form will generate a weak DES hash without a safe salt. You should definitifely use the function [password_hash()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) instead. Have a look at Anti-weakpasswords answer.

Comment: I agree, yet as I stated in my answer, it's an example script (and can be modified). If the OP has PHP 5.5 on the server then by all means to use PHP's `password()` function. @martinstoeckli

Comment: @Fred-ii- - Note that there is also a [compatibility pack](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat/blob/master/lib/password.php) in form of a simple PHP file for PHP version 5.3.7 and higher. For versions before 5.3.7 i wrote [example code](http://www.martinstoeckli.ch/php/php.html#bcrypt) to use BCrypt.

Comment: Thanks @martinstoeckli - I did see it before but didn't have a chance to try it out yet. Then each time I had some free time on my hands (to test), I was quickly distracted by another job therefore forgetting; again. (lol) I will make of "note" of it now so this time I won't forget. Thanks again for the info, cheers. And thanks for the example code :)

Comment: @Fred-ii- - Well that's the problem with free time... good luck anyway.

Comment: I've saved both of them now and in my "to do" folder as we speak. @martinstoeckli Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

If you're on PHP 5.5 or later, there's the built-in password_hash() and password_verify() with Bcrypt - if you're on PHP 5.3.7 or later, there's the [password_compat](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat) compatibility library; all this is per the [PHP.net Safe Password Hashing FAQ entry](https://www.php.net/manual/en/faq.passwords.php).

Essentially, on PHP 5.3.7 and above, replace the old crypt() with password_hash() and password_verify().

See [my answer to PHP Secure password generation and storage](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22118442/1967612) for some more details on cost choice, but it boils down to the very simple:

```
<?php
/**
 * In this case, we want to increase the default cost for BCRYPT to 12.
 * Note that we also switched to BCRYPT, which will always be 60 characters.
 */
$options = [
    'cost' => 12,
];
echo password_hash("rasmuslerdorf", PASSWORD_BCRYPT, $options)."\n";
?>
```

to generate the hash, then you store the output string, and then verify with:

```
<?php
// See the password_hash() example to see where this came from.
$hash = '$2y$07$BCryptRequires22Chrcte/VlQH0piJtjXl.0t1XkA8pw9dMXTpOq';

if (password_verify('rasmuslerdorf', $hash)) {
    echo 'Password is valid!';
} else {
    echo 'Invalid password.';
}
?>
```

Both examples come from the [PHP.net Password Hashing page](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.password.php).

Comment: awesome, only bit I don't understand is the $hash bit, do I simply set its value to a random password generated by pasword hash?

Comment: Per the docs, "The used algorithm, cost and salt are returned as part of the hash. Therefore, all information that's needed to verify the hash is included in it." - therefore in the verify, $hash is set equal to whatever the initial password_hash() was; you'd use password_hash() only when a user sets or changes a password - password_verify() is what you use when the log in, passing in first the password they typed, and second the previous password_hash() result which you stored in your database/text file/whatever storage you're using.